# PHP explode string by dot if the next character is a space or an uppercase alphabetic character

Tags: php, string, explode

I have a paragraph that looks like this:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply (not **1.2%**) dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industr**y. L**orem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen boo**k. I**t has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchang**ed. I**t was popularised in the 1960s

I want to split this in pharagraph in phrases ended by a dot `.` but only when that dot is at the end of a phrase, not in the middle (like `1.2%`) and when there is an `UPPERCASE` character after it(and maybe a blank space too). For example if i use:

```
$arr = explode('.', $paragraph);
```

it will split that paragraph at each occurrence of that `.`.

Is there a fast and clean way to obtain that? If yes can somebody please help me understand it?

Comment: Shouldn't just `$arr = explode('. ', $paragraph);` work? (add a space after the dot). However, it will probably result in grammatically incorrect text since a paragraph can consist of multiple sentences. Doing it correct automatically would probably require some kind of AI or extensive rule engine.

Comment: I second the `explode(". ", $paragraph);` idea. It's by far the simplest. Since the goal is to extract the sentences from a paragraph, regardless of "stop/full stop", this is the simplest quickest way to achieve the objective. Regex may be more efficient and run faster (noticeable on very long paragraphs maybe) but in terms of "golf code" this one wins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex to match dot that is before uppercase character or space and use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split string based on regex match.

```
$arr = preg_split("/\.\s?(?=[A-Z])/", $paragraph);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/UGNM0)

Comment: too quick for me, but i was about to answer `/\.\s?(?=[A-Z])/` instead..

Comment: @Kaddath You're right, it cause remove additional space from first of items

Comment: There is a new line in item 1.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank youuuuu! :D It works perfectly <3 Thank you, all 3 of you!

Comment: This is the final form i'm going with: `/\.\s*?(?=[A-Z])/` is it ok? (it also splits the \n )

Comment: @emma Yes also remove new line

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_split('/\.[\s|$]/', $input_line);`.

That will split on dot and either space or new line.

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qiC
https://3v4l.org/FOaHu

Comment: **explode ... if the next character is a space or an uppercase** but you did not pay attention to it. Also your code match last dot in end of string

Comment: @Mohammad Doesn't matter if there is a uppercase character or not. What OP believes is the correct method is not always true. Go read about the square wheels.

Comment: Hei @Andreas, thank you for taking time to help me i really appreciate it but i've already used your previous comment answer and Mohammad's answer aswell :(